# How can I have segmented mesh using shader in unity 3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, shader

I am trying to get the following image like result: 
[Segmented Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xa4M6.png)

I have tried to use setReplacementShader like the following script. I have attached the script to a main camera.

```
public class ReplaceShader : MonoBehaviour {


public Shader newShader;
void Update () {
    GetComponent<Camera>().SetReplacementShader (newShader,"RenderType");

}

}
```

Where my shader code is :

```
Shader "Custom/NewShader" {

SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Opaque" }
    Pass{Color(1,0,0,0)}
    }
SubShader {
    Tags { "RenderType"="Fade" }
    Pass{Color(0,0,1,0)}
    }

}
```

But it does not give any expected result. In one simple scene it paints everything including the terrain to become red. In another large scene it does nothing, forcefully shows the skybox instead of the regular scene. What can I do to solve this?

Comment: Please see the image in the [Segmented Image] link

Comment: You only need to call SetReplacementShader once. You don't need to do it every frame. Also, if you want to render the same scene twice on the screen, you need two cameras: one with the replaced shader, one without, and each one set to render to a different half of the screen.

Comment: I did as u said, but nothing changes. I have written the SetReplacementShader in a Start() method and attached the script to a camera. Nothing changes, except that it no longer acts weird meaning forcefully show the skybox only.

Comment: For example I want to color all the building red and all the car in the scene blue.is there any way to do that?

Comment: I've used replacement shader like...once. The problem with your setup is that shaders treat all things equally, unless there's some data the shader can see that makes them unequal. For instance, in your shader you can create two different passes and supply a different `Tag` for them (e.g. `Tags { "color"="red" }`), then on each object's material, you call [`SetOverrideTag("color","red")`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Material.SetOverrideTag.html) and it will render with that pass and only that pass. Objects that don't have the tag set won't be rendered at all.